This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component
I am facing above error in my next js app with typescript, it was working quite find, I just added some more pages for reset Password and forget Password.
I already have an app directory which contains pages, components, constants and types folders. Now I added src directory to contain redux related code and lib code.
I am facing this error no matter which page I load, I am unable to run my application. I have used "use client" in every client file, only not in page.tsx file because that is a server file.
These are the logs when I run the application
 ⨯ [Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.] {
  digest: '3931836113'
}
 ○ Compiling /auth/setupPassword ...
 ✓ Compiled /auth/setupPassword in 8.6s (858 modules)
 ⨯ [Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.] {
  digest: '3931836113'
}
 ⨯ [Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.] {
  digest: '3931836113'
}
 GET / 500 in 5474ms
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 429ms (484 modules)
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 697ms
 ⨯ [Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.] {
  digest: '3931836113'
}
 GET / 500 in 201ms
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 35ms

 ○ Compiling /auth/login ...
 ✓ Compiled /auth/login in 2.1s (1049 modules)
 ⨯ [Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.] {
  digest: '3931836113'
}
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 GET /auth/login 500 in 2382ms
 ⨯ [Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.] {
  digest: '3931836113'
}
 GET / 500 in 73ms
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 176ms (605 modules)
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 289ms

And this is the error I see when I build the application
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 15.1.0

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types ...
   Collecting page data ...
   Generating static pages (0/9) ...
Error occurred prerendering page "/_not-found". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: This function is not supported in React Server Components. Please only use this export in a Client Component.
    at n (D:\admitpath-frontend\.next\server\chunks\736.js:3:60062)
    at ek (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:13368)
    at e (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:17266)
    at e$ (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:17728)
    at Object.toJSON (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:14874)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eU (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:26231)
    at eB (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:26461)
    at eq (D:\admitpath-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:84:27015)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
Export encountered an error on /_not-found/page: /_not-found, exiting the build.
 ⨯ Static worker exited with code: 1 and signal: null

I have tried rebooting the application, I also have tried moving redux and lib folder to the root and deleting src folder. I have also tried deleting .next folder and reinstalling node modules. But I am still facing this error.
Please let me know if anyone is familiar with this error, it would be a huge help.
Thanks.

You will have to post the code so that we can check it out.

Thanks for the concern. But I actually resolved the issue. I knew it was related to mentioning 'use client' directive at top of client files which I already had. But I made one change recently by adding redux store in main layout.tsx file which was a server render file and it didn't need use client directive, but it needed it after adding redux.
